# Mendeley - how can I find folders that a particular reference is associated to?

Tags: citations, mendeley

In Mendeley Desktop, I can view all papers in a particular folder. Also I can filter my references according to tags and also check which tags belong to a particular reference.

But is there any possibility to check which folders belong to a specific reference? Basically going the opposite direction in the folder-reference association?

Comment: Interesting. Do you have any use case for this?

Comment: The use case is if I initially put the reference into some folders but later want to check whether I have put the reference into all folders I intended to (in that sense using the folders quasi as tags or keywords).